# How to exclude a module from app.module for production builds?

Tags: angular, webpack, ngrx

In my `app.module.ts` file I have a module `StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 50}),` that is currently in use. However, I want to exclude this from the Production environment.

I tried to use conditional logic in `app.module.ts` file using the `isProdMode()` function, however function calls are not allowed there.

I also have two separate Webpack config files `webpack.config.dev.js` and `webpack.config.prod.js`. I've look through several possible solutions (like adding conditional logic to the `app.module.ts` file and using `exclude:` in the webpack config, but none of them seem to work...

Any ideas how to remove the module when building the app in Prod environment?

Comment: `process.env.NODE_ENV !== production {require statement for that module}` ?

Comment: So I tried adding `isDevEnv ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({maxAge: 50}) : [],` in my app.module.ts under `imports: []` but the module is still available even when `const isDevEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";` resolves to false. Any ideas?

Comment: Weird because in the final bundle webpack usually removes those dead code paths... specially with an "if" statement

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
 environment.production
      ? []
      : StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument(}),
```